# Python tkinter Treeview populate from tuple

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, tk-toolkit, ttk

Is there a way to populate a tkinter TreeView from a tuple?

Example list of tuples:

```
list_sbc_team = [(Player1,100),(Player2,500),(Player3,1000)]
```

I would now like to fill my tkinter TreeView based on that list of tuples.

My Treeview coding looks like that:

```
sbc_listbox = ttk.Treeview(
    frame_treeview_entries_sbc_labelframe,
    columns=(
        "Player",
        "Price",
    ),  
    selectmode="browse",  
    show="headings", 
)
sbc_listbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w", pady=15)

# Treeview layout
sbc_listbox.heading("#1", text="Player", anchor=tk.W)
sbc_listbox.heading("#2", text="Price", anchor=tk.W)

listbox.column("#1", stretch=tk.YES, minwidth=100, width=155)
listbox.column("#2", stretch=tk.YES, minwidth=100, width=100)
```

Anyone can help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that doesn't rely on scraping a website. Just add a hard-coded tuple that you're trying to insert, the treeview widget doesn't care where that tuple comes from.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have edited my post, so ok ?

Comment: It's definitely better. However, it would be better if it were complete. That means import statements, the creation of the root window, and a call to mainloop. The less work someone has to do to reproduce the problem, the more likely it is that you'll get an answer.

Comment: In the example tuple, is `Player1` an object or a string?

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
for values in list_sbc_team:
    GUI.sbc_listbox.insert("", "end", values=values)
```